# JTextPane in a JScrollPane in a JPanel in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, layout-manager

What I am trying to do is make it so the JTextPane takes up as much space as possible in the JPanel.
For my UpdateInfoPanel I am using:

```
public class UpdateInfoPanel extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 257125249175323679L;

private JTextPane textPane;

public UpdateInfoPanel(){
    textPane = new JTextPane();
    textPane.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    textPane.setEditable(false);
    textPane.setMargin(null);
    textPane.setContentType("text/html");
    textPane.setText("<html><body style=\"font: Arial; color: white; padding: 5px; padding-top: 0;\"><h1 style=\"padding-top: 0;\">News</h1></body></html>");
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
    add(scrollPane);
    setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    textPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
}
}
```

And for my frame I simply create an instance of this and put it in BorderLayout.CENTER.
Currently this is how it looks. White border is the scroll pane, black is the textpane. **What I want to do is have the borders be at the edge of the panel.**
![][1]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). What is your question?

Comment: My question is how do I make it so that the borders stretch out to the sides dynamically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you setting layout of your panel?

```
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

If you dont need the border of textpane do `textPane.setBorder(null);`
Dont extend the `JPanel`. You can create is as you create the `JTextPane`.

Comment: The way I learned to do this was to always extend JPanel and then add that to a specific layout in my main frame. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: *"..always extend JPanel.."*  The only time it is necessary to extend panel is when you have custom rendering (e.g. a BG image) over which you intend to position components using layouts.  In other cases just keep a reference to a standard panel.  If the rendering inside it is custom,  do that in an image (displayed in a label).